# IP whitelisting in google container engine with ingress not working

Tags: kubernetes, whitelist

I am trying to whitelist IPs that can access my application. I created http-balancer by following this tutorial. https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer

After creating the service with `NodePort` I created an `ingress.yaml` file that looks like the one below. I have created a global static ip and setup a domain name.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: <global-static-ip>
spec:
  rules:
  - host: <domain_name>
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
            serviceName: nginx
            servicePort: 80
```

This above yaml file works fine and I am able to access the "Welcome to Nginx" page.

But when I add the IPs to be whitelisted it does not seem to work and still allows other IPs that are not whitelisted.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: <global-static-ip>
    ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "xx.xx.xx.xxx/32"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: <domain_name>
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
            serviceName: nginx
            servicePort: 80
```

Reference: 
http://container-solutions.com/kubernetes-quick-tip/
https://docs.giantswarm.io/guides/advanced-ingress-configuration/

Answer (score 1):

I have not worked with Ingress but as per normal nginx rules you need to deny all and then allow the whitelist IPS

```
          `location / {
                    proxy_pass https://xxx.xx.xx.xx:8080 
                    allow xx.xx.xx.xxx/32; 
                    deny all; 
                     allow xx.xx.xx.xxx/32; 
           }`
```

Which inturn wont allow your non-Whitelisted IP's.

Answer (score 0):

The references you provided use the [Nginx-based ingress controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/).

Ingress on GKE uses [http(s) load balancer](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/). Currently the http(s) load balancer on GCP does not support the firewall rules to allow or deny traffic by IPs.

You can:

Block the source ip in web server or application by yourself.

Or

Try to install [nginx-based ingress controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/deploy).